# Creating conditional statement for the first_or_create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the first_or_create method when allowing my User to sign in from twitter.

However I'd like to create a conditional statement depending on if it's a first or create.

If it's first (and the user was present) I'd like to redirect them to X place. If the user get's created I'd like to redirect them to Y place.

Currently what I have in my controller is:

```
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  # returned from the model
  if user.save
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to campaigns_path, notice: "Signed in"
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'Unable to sign you in!'
  end
end
```

I tried

```
elsif user.exists?
```

but that didn't work. My model looks like this:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider             = auth.provider
    user.profile_image_url    = auth.info.image
    user.followers_count      = auth.followers_count
    user.uid                  = auth.uid
    user.access_token         = auth.credentials.token
    user.access_token_secret  = auth.credentials.secret
    user.name                 = auth.info.name
    user.nickname             = auth.info.nickname
    user.website              = auth.info.urls.website
    user.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `user.persisted?` instead of `user.exists?`?

Comment: doesn't seem to have an impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create (first_or_*create*) saves the model, so all persistence checks will not show any difference, instead i would try `first_or_initialize`

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
```

Then you need to remove this line from the method body

```
user.save
```

and tweak the condition a bit

```
if user.persisted?
  user.save # unless you have more editing first
  # handle old user
elsif user.save
  # this means the user is saved successfully
else
  # new user but wasn't saved
end
```

Comment: for some reason an old user still triggers persisted

Comment: the old user should be persisted, but not the new one.

Comment: (old user = result of first, persisted = true), (new user = result of initialize, persisted = false)

Comment: new one goes into user.persisted too for some reason

Comment: o i know, you need to remove `user.save` from the omniauth method, and call save after you enter the `if`

Comment: are you sure it works? cause i was testing it and i think it shouldn't work yet, double check plz, i think the data in the block won't be saved in the case of the `first`

Comment: ok nvm, you don't want to save it when you get 'first', i was over thinking it.